# Having trouble ending a do/while loop depending on a boolean - C++

Tags: c++, comparison, boolean, return, do-while

Fixed. Thank You.

In my code below, it compiles and runs but gets stuck in the do/while loop. The return values are working but the while loop must not recognize it and it goes indefinitely. I can receive returns of true and false; both do not stop the loop. Really lost here and cannot find an answer. Thank you.

```
//helper function for inputGuess
//checks if the user's guess is in the lowercase alphabet and that
//  it has not been guessed before
bool Hangman::validGuess() {
  //checks if the character guess is in the lowercase alphabet
  if (guess >= 97 && guess <= 122) {
    //checks if the user's guess has been guessed previously
    if (guessed.size() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < guessed.size(); i++) {
        cout << "enter for\n";
        cout << "guess[i]: " << guessed[i] << endl;
        if (guess != guessed[i]) {
          cout << "1st true: guess has not been guessed\n";
          return true;
        }
        else {
          cout << "1st false: same letter\n";
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      cout << "2nd true: guessed size is 0\n";
      return true;
    }
  }
  else {
    cout << "2nd false: not alphabet\n";
    return false;
  }
}

//gets input for guess, checks if guess is valid, adds guess to guessed
void Hangman::inputGuess() {
  bool valid = false;
  do {
    cout << "Please enter your guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    cout << endl;
    valid = validGuess();
    cout << "valid: " << valid << endl;
  } while (valid == false);
  guessed.push_back(guess);
}
```

Comment: You can't always assume the system you're running on uses ASCII. Even if you do, `'a'` is much clearer than 97. Keep in mind there's an `islower` function as well.

Comment: I think the code you have shown is not the problem in itself, but it's also not complete. I would think that there is another outer loop and you are stuck in this outer loop. Please add the rest of your code (if it is not too much).

Comment: your code shall not compile (`guess` is not declared in `validGuess()`), so how did you manage to get it to run???

Comment: I think you are right Daniel; it may be getting stuck in my constructor that calls the function. Let me have a closer look; thank you. Edit: with a closer look; that was the problem, my constructor was stuck in a loop that called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an undefined return case when `guessed` is empty, as it falls through and there is no default return.

Regardless, this code seems overly complex.  Something like this might be better:

```
bool HangMan::validGuess() {
    //checks if the character guess is in the lowercase alphabet
    if (isalpha(guess)) {
        //checks if the user's guess has been guessed previously
        if (find(guessed.begin(), guessed.end(), guess) != guessed.end()) {
            cout << "1st false: same letter\n";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            cout << "1st true: guess has not been guessed\n";
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "2nd false: not alphabet\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass guess as a parameter to  validGuess() that's your problem.  try adding

```
this->guess
```

instead of just guess.

Comment: It looks like a global variable, since it is also not defined in `inputGuess()`.

Comment: @Daniel: I would guess a class member, but yes I agree its scope is greater than either function, and this "answer" may be a stylistic improvement but isn't going to solve the problem.

Comment: yeah, I see.  still. he "should" pass it.  we need to see the rest of the class, maybe it's an instance problem, like the function is static  etc.  if it's a class var, try adding the scope resolution

Comment: guess is declared in private as part of the hangman class; so it does not need to be passed. guessed is a blank vector also declared in private as part of the hangman class.

Comment: try  this->guess   c# handles well but c++ might need it